# "Lightbox" for tables

Tags: r, quarto

I was wondering if someone has an idea for a similar [lightbox feature](https://github.com/quarto-ext/lightbox) for tables in R. For instance, in the following MWE I have a table using `kableExtra` with many columns that are thus displayed automatically using a scroll box since it is too wide. What I would like is a button or something to click on which than expands the table similar to the lightbox feature showing all columns.

````
---
title: "Lightbox and tables"
format: html
editor: source
execute: 
  warning: false
  message: false
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
bind_cols(iris, iris, iris) |> 
  head(10) |> 
  kbl() |> 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed")
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the `as_image()` function:

````
---
title: "Lightbox Table Example"
format: html
filters:
  - lightbox
lightbox: auto
execute: 
  warning: false
  message: false
---


```{r}
#| lightbox:
#|   description: We see our iris dataset here three times.
#| out.height: "50%"
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
bind_cols(iris, iris, iris) |> 
  head(10) |> 
  kbl() |> 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed") |> 
  as_image(zoom = 1.5, file = "table_1.png")
```
````